# ZF2 Shared Modules Event Manager

Tags: events, zend-framework2

I need to implement in each of my modules an event trigger when something specific happens. I also need that all the other modules that must to do some work when that event is trigger, be aware of it.

I'm trying to create some common endpoint where I can send my triggers, and where all the modules need to be listening, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how can I achieve that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the comments to @Andrew's answer, as long as your controller extends the `AbstractActionController` (which it most likely does) it's already EventManager aware, so you can just go ahead and trigger any event you like in a controller action simply by doing...

```
<?php
namespace Application/Controller;

// usual use statements omitted for brevity ..

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // trigger MyEvent
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger('MyEvent', $this);
    }

}
```

To listen to that event in the bootstrap of some other module, do the following

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    // get the shared events manager 
    $sem = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    // listen to 'MyEvent' when triggered by the IndexController
    $sem->attach('Application\Controller\IndexController', 'MyEvent', function($e) {
        // do something...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of good articles on this:

http://www.mwop.net/blog/266-Using-the-ZF2-EventManager.html

http://www.eschrade.com/page/zend-framework-2-event-manager/

It's quite easy to make your modules listen to an event which is application wide, and then perform some task when triggered. There should be more than enough info in those two to get you started.

If you give an example of what you want I can help with an example of how you can go about it.

Comment: the ideia, in a nutshell, is to trigger an event in my IndexController of my ModuleA, and in another ModuleB, let's say in my Module.php onBootstrap ou in a Service, i want to attach a function and listen for that event, and when he's triggered, do some work..

Comment: and when do you want to trigger the event?