# How to use ZF2's EventManager over multiple classes (and modules)?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am having the following setup: In a controller I trigger an event and I want to attach multiple listeners to it at other places.

Currently I have the following listener in my **onBootstrap**:

```
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('EventManager')->attach('*', function($e) {
    var_dump($e->getName());
});
```

The following piece of code as a **factory**:

```
'Application\Controller\Foo' => function(ControllerManager $cm) {
    $eventManager = $cm->getServiceLocator()->get('EventManager');
    $controller = new \Application\Controller\FooController();
    $controller->setEventManager($eventManager);
    return $controller;
},
```

And finally the following trigger within my **controller**:

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('foo-finished', 'finishedAction', array(
    'obj' => $foo->someObject()
));
```

So it should both be the same `EventManager` as I receive it from the service locator and inject it into the controller. Still I get no output at all. I also tried using `$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()` when attaching to events, but this only gives me the ZF internal events.

I read about the `SharedEventManager`, but I do not fully understand why I should pass a context. I tried it like this (which is as I understood it), but still no output.

```
$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('EventManager')
    ->getSharedManager()
    ->attach('finishedAction', '*', function() { ... });
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I just want to trigger events and catch them in possibly different modules, but it seems to be made so complicated...

Comment: See the answer here for an example -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227693/zf2-shared-modules-event-manager/15243247#15243247

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `EventManager` service is not shared, this means that every time you call `$serviceLocator->get('EventManager')` you will get a different instance, that's why you should use the `SharedEventManager` - take a look at @Crisp's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227693/zf2-shared-modules-event-manager/15243247#15243247) to see how to use it.

One more tip: Don't try to inject the Mvc EventManager in your objects, each object should trigger their own events.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (not the order of getEventManager and getSharedManager), also note the order of event name and the context (or identifier).

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('*', 'finishedAction', function() { ... });
```

Regards!